# Visual Studio 2019 Project - Package - Illegal Characters in Path

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

I am seeing the following error on the "Package" tab when viewing the project properties for a Visual Studio 2019 project.  Other developers are seeing the same message on their machines.

This is a .Net Standard 2.0 class library.  It builds successfully and generates a valid NuGet package on build as expected.  However, the property page for this tab no longer loads in the development environment.

Has anyone experienced this before?

[image: Illegal Characters in Path]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to narrow this down to an empty element in the .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <PackageLicenseFile>
   </PackageLicenseFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Removing the "PackageLicenseFile" group restored the property page.